# How to Emulate a Dynamic Display in C Code

Tags: c, systems-programming

I have written a code which can convert any Input Integer to equlivalent LED Display. I want to pass my system's time as an Input to this Function and get an LED Display for the same.

Example: 
Consider these 2 Inputs:

```
(system time = 10:12:00)
(system time = 11:10:04)
```

Problem:

The Screen Output should Overwrite the Previous Output for "10:12:00" with "11:10:04" such that the application user should get a feeling of an 'Inplace' Dynamic Display.

Requesting you to please provide some hint on how to achieve this in "C" Code. (My platform is GNU/Linux)

Thanks.

Best Regards,

Sandeep Singh

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is something like:

```
printf("\r%s", time_string);
```

As far as getting the time as a string, you can retrieve the time with `time()`, convert to local time broken down into fields with [`localtime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime), and put a format of your choice in a string with [`strftime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime).

Answer (score 1):

write your string and then as much backspaces ('\b') as needed to erase this string before writing another one.